# Can you break a while loop from outside the loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, boolean-expression

Can you break a while loop from outside the loop? Here's a (very simple) example of what I'm trying to do: I want to ask for continuous inside a While loop, but when the input is 'exit', I want the while loop to break!

```
active = True

def inputHandler(value):
    if value == 'exit':
        active = False

while active is True:
    userInput = input("Input here: ")
    inputHandler(userInput)
```

Comment: `while active:` or if you insist `while active == True:` but not `is True`

Comment: Better ways to do this: `raise` some exception, call `sys.exit`, have the `while`condition itself check the input (possibly with another function)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your case, in `inputHandler`, you are creating a new variable called `active` and storing `False` in it. This will not affect the module level  `active`.

To fix this, you need to explicitly say that `active` is not a new variable, but the one declared at the top of the module, with the `global` keyword, like this

```
def inputHandler(value):
    global active

    if value == 'exit':
        active = False
```

---

But, please note that the proper way to do this would be to return the result of `inputHandler` and store it back in `active`.

```
def inputHandler(value):
    return value != 'exit'

while active:
    userInput = input("Input here: ")
    active = inputHandler(userInput)
```

If you look at the `while` loop, we used `while active:`. In Python you either have to use `==` to compare the values, or simply rely on the truthiness of the value. `is` operator should be used only when you need to check if the values are one and the same.

---

But, if you totally want to avoid this, you can simply use [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) function which breaks out automatically when the sentinel value is met.

```
for value in iter(lambda: input("Input here: "), 'exit'):
    inputHandler(value)
```

Now, `iter` will keep executing the function passed to it, till the function returns the sentinel value (second parameter) passed to it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can indeed do it that way, with a tweak: make `active` global.

```
global active
active = True

def inputHandler(value):
    global active
    if value == 'exit':
        active = False

while active:
    userInput = input("Input here: ")
    inputHandler(userInput)
```

(I also changed `while active is True` to just `while active` because the former is redundant.)

Comment: when you don't have `global active` python creates a local variable `active` that only exists inside of the `inputHandler` function.

Answer (score 1):

Others have already stated why your code fails. Alternatively you break it down to some very simple logic.

```
while True:
    userInput = input("Input here: ")
    if userInput == 'exit':
        break
```