# Break / Stop while loop from user input at the Matlab command line

Tags: matlab, while-loop, infinite-loop

I am attempting to create a while loop that will loop continuously until input from the user at the command line.

I have tried two implementations of this the first, the first derived from this bit of [python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33906842/8755102). The problem being that you must enter something other than exit every time you want to iterate through loop.

```matlab
    global active
    active = true;

        while active == true
            userInput = input('enter: ','s');
            inputHandler(userInput)
            disp(rand)
            pause(1);
        end

        function inputHandler(value)
            global active
            if value == 'exit'
                active = false;
            end
        end
```

The second was

```
global loopFlag
loopFlag = true

while loopFlag == true
    %some awesome code happens here
end
```

with the idea being that you could enter at the command line `loopFlag = false` while the code was executing and it would stop.
I know this can be done through the use of a [toggle button](https://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2010/12/03/how-to-loop-until-a-button-is-pushed-in-matlab/) but I would prefer not to have to go that route unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: So what's wrong with the first implementation?

Comment: @LuisMendo you must enter something every time you want to loop. I need to the loop to run by itself until it sees an input from the command line

Comment: I don't know a way for the command window to detect a key press, other than `input`, which as you've seen stops the program execution while waiting for input. You could perhaps create a figure and set its `'WindowKeyPressFcn'` so that it changes its `UserData` from true to false. The `while` loop in the program would then be `while get(figureHandle,'UserData')`

Answer (score -1):

```
active = true;
while active == true
   active = input('Enter true or false ' );
   disp(rand)
   pause(1)
end
```

Comment: Nivi, this method has the same outcome as my first attempt. You must enter a value every iteration of the loop in order to continue. The idea was that the loop will run continuously until a command is entered to stop it.

Comment: I see, I thought you wanted to better your prev code. I have done this in Labview but not Matlab. I think you can do this using GUIs though.